# Use a variable returned in a getter method in another class

Tags: java, class, variables, syntax, getter

I am still learning but seem to fall at what should be very simple hurdles; my strong points seem to be with the logic of equations but I possess little skill at remembering and implementing functions and correct simple syntax's.

The class that I am implementing the method in is MyClass, the method that I want to define the variable taken from the other class is establishIrEvent. The class that I want to collect the variable from is IREvent, the getter method that returns the variable in this class that I want to collect is getX.

Now for the code:

Getter method from IREvent class:

```
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
```

Method that I want to use that variable in to assign, (with my terribly poor attempt) in MyClass:

```
public void establishIrEvent(IREvent arg0) {

    int source = (IREvent)arg0.getX();

}
```

Any advice will be hugely appreciated and fingers crossed this question may aid someone else in a similar pickle! Please ask for any more info as I always seem to miss something or ask a question that annoys an experienced developer somewhat.

Comment: Why are you casting int to IREvent? Moreover you're assigning result to string.

Comment: I forgot to change that, I am trying to assign to an int, thank you I'll edit

Comment: You didn't mention any problem, but I think that your code won't compile. Try `String source=String.valueOf(arg0.getX());` You can't cast int to String. You need to convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.  First, you are trying to assign an `int` to a `String` because `getX` returns `int` and the `source` variable is a `String`.  if you want to do this, then try :

```
String source = Integer.toString(arg0.getX());
```

Second, and less of an issue, there is no need to cast `arg0` to `IREvent` as it's already defined as that in the `establishIrEvent` method.

Comment: thank you, I was not trying to convert to String, that was me being a tool

Comment: So i took what you answered and put int xCord = arg0.getX();

Comment: All is working beautifully, thank you! Sorry for my ignorance but I have to start somewhere... I am a "for fun" learner but it is incredibly how often "for fun" translates to "make yourself cry for the hell of it"!

Answer (score 1):

`getX()` returns an int so you could do the following

```
public void establishIrEvent(IREvent arg0) {

   int x = arg0.getX(); // local variable x which is the x from the IREvent class
   String source = Integer.toString(x); // if that's what the source string should be given x

}
```

That code should compile and run OK but it's still useless because nothing is altered by the call to `establishIrEvent(IREvent arg0)`, because both variables x and source are discarded after the call.  So you probably want to have the `x` and/or the `source` variable as member variables of the class where `establishIrEvent(IREvent arg0)` is a method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the below statement:

```
String source = (IREvent)arg0.getX();
```

Problem: getX() method of IREvent is returning int and you are trying to assign it to String by  casting the return type to IREvent. Eventually making everyone confused including JVM and yourself.

I am not sure whether you need the value as String if that is the case then you need to do like this:

```
String source = String.valueOf(arg0.getX());
```

Answer (score 1):

You already did most of the work. The thing is that `arg0.getX()` returns an `int`. This `int` is not a String that you are assigning it to, so you must convert it to the `int` type. You tried to convert (typecast) it to the `IREvent` type which is wrong. Try something like this:

```
public void establishIrEvent(IREvent arg0) {
     String source = String.valueOf(arg0.getX());
}
```

I advise you to use the Eclipse IDE and all this stuff will be much easier to cope with. Eclipse IDE will provide you with an instant compiler error and warning messages and make good suggestions.